# Same cURL code, different results with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, cookies

When I try to save cookies without Laravel,it's saved.But with Laravel I can't find the cookie file(Searched everywhere :) ).

Here is the code(part):

```
         ...Some php code...

        $dataJSON = json_encode($dataPost);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataJSON);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"); //even with the realpath ,no difference

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);


        print_r($result);

        curl_close($curl);
```

Is it a Routing problem?

Comment: *"cookie.txt"); //even with the realpath ,no difference* Can't you just set a path that's known to you rather than trying figure out the working directory of the process?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you,it's working.I was thinking"ok,if it's not working with realpath,it is not a path problem".But yes,it was a path problem.

Comment: [realpath()](https://php.net/realpath) just expands and normalises a path; it doesn't alter it to make it point elsewhere.